# memcpy over a structure with another structure not working in C

Tags: c

So There have already been plenty of questions about copying structure by assigning or using memcpy. Now i wrote a small programm with having two structures:

```
typedef struct {

 int b;
} myStruct2;

typedef struct {

 int a;
 myStruct2* sub_struct;
} myStruct;
```

So now I tried to define two structures and then use a memcpy over them like this (I am handling NULL pointers after allocating memory, just left it out for easier reading):

```
myStruct* var_one = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
var_one->sub_struct = malloc(sizeof(myStruct2));

var_one->a = 10;
var_one->sub_struct->b = 111;

myStruct* var_two = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
var_two->sub_struct = malloc(sizeof(myStruct2));

var_two->a = 22;
var_two->sub_struct->b = 2222;

printf("%d und %d\n", var_two->a, var_two->sub_struct->b);


memcpy(var_two, var_one, sizeof(myStruct));


printf("%d und %d\n", var_two->a, var_two->sub_struct->b);
```

Sofar everything works fine and as expected. But know if I do:

```
free(var_one->sub_struct);
free(var_one);

printf("%d und %d\n", var_two->a, var_two->sub_struct->b);
```

The second printf is giving me the error:
    Invalid read of size 4;

Can someone explain me maybe why? The memory for the sub-structure of var_two has been allocated separately, and I thought that memcpy is just copying a piece of memory? So why is freeing the first sub-structure influencing the second one?

Comment: `memcpy` doesn't preform a deep copy. If you won't to follow pointers and copy objects write a custom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your `memcpy` you also copied the pointer to the sub struct. If you then free the original, you have freed the memory pointed to (that you have just copied).

So `var_two->sub_struct` now points to the memory that `var_one->sub_struct` points to. With `free(var_one->sub_struct)` you have effectively freed what `var_two->sub_struct` now was pointing to.

Btw, the memory `var_two->sub_struct` was pointing to is now lost.

Comment: ok thank you a lot! so I have in these cases manually to copy the substructures right?